# Nullable type GetType() throws exception

Tags: c#, .net

I just got this quiz from a colleague that is driving me crazy. For this snippet of code:

```
var x = new Int32?();
string text = x.ToString(); // No exception
Console.WriteLine(text);
Type type = x.GetType(); // Bang!
```

Why does the first part .ToString() works without throwing an exception and then the call to GetType() throws a NullReferenceException ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`ToString` is [overridden in `Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hd15ket.aspx), so no boxing is involved to make the call.

`GetType()` isn't a virtual method, so isn't (and can't be) overridden, so the value is boxed before the call is made... and boxing a null value of a nullable value type gives a null reference.

The reason for boxing is in section 7.5.5 of the C# 4 spec:

> If `M` is an instance function member declared in a *reference-type*:
>
> - ...
> - If the type of `E` is a *value-type*, a boxing conversion (4.3.1) is performed to convert `E` to type `object`, and `E` is considered to be of type `object` in the following steps. In this case, `M` could only be a member of `System.Object`

Note that if you had:

```
var x = new Int32?(10);
```

you'd end up with the type being the same as `typeof(int)`, again due to boxing. There is no way of creating a value `foo` such that `foo.GetType()` returns a nullable value type, using the normal `GetType()` method. (You could create a *new* `GetType()` method of course, but that's a side issue :)

(The use of "Bang!" suggests the author of said quiz may be me. Apologies for driving you crazy if that's the case.)

Comment: Ok .. but why then replacing the last line with: var boxed = (Int32) x; throws InvalidOperationException instead? Isn't that boxing and should throw the same exception?

Comment: @kabaros: No, that's not boxing at all - neither `Int32?` nor `Int32` are reference types. It's an explicit conversion described in section 6.2.3 of the C# 4 spec.

Comment: Oh yeah of course, that makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot. Great book by the way so you're forgiven for driving us crazy :)