# Methods on Nullable types

Tags: c#, nullable

Can someone explain why is it possible to call methods on `null` instance?

```
int? num = null;

var s1 = num.ToString();
var s2 = num.HasValue;
var s3 = num.GetHashCode();
var s4 = num.GetValueOrDefault();

var s5 = num.Value; // InvalidOperationException
var s6 = num.GetType(); // NullReferenceException
```

I can check the `num` is `null` in a debug mode, so how is it possible that `ToString` method or `HasValue` getter can be called on `null` instance, but for `Value` and `GetType` it is not possible? All of them are methods or properties on `Nullable<>` type or not?

I would naturally expect the `Value` getter returns `null` value, similarly as the `HasValue` returns `false`. I would expect too, that `GetType` returns `Nullable<int>` type info, or `num is int?` or `num is Nullable<int>` works. Why doesn't it work? How can I check the `num` is a nullable type?

Creating an instance doesn't change anything on that:

```
Nullable<int> num = new Nullable<int>();
```

What's behind the scene?

Comment: As of the docs. of `Nullable.ToString`: "The text representation of the value of the current Nullable<T> object if the HasValue property is true, **or an empty string ("") if the HasValue property is false.**"

Comment: `Nullable<T>` is a struct, and therefor can't actually be `null`. It's a special treatment by the compiler to enable you to do `int? num = null` in the first place.

Comment: Mostly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725631/nullable-type-gettype-throws-exception. It explains already the core questions why `ToString` works and `GetType` throws a `NullReferenceException`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Nullable<T>` has a bit of compiler magic that makes it *appear* as if there was a `null` value. But there isn't. Basically, since `Nullable<T>` is a value type, it cannot be `null` to begin with. Its nullability is determined whether there is a value or not. This means that you can call `HasValue` (which is important, since that's what the compiler inserts when you write `num == null`) and other methods that don't depend on a value being present.

As for a few specific points:

- `ToString` is an implementation that works similar to how `null` values are converted to string when used in string concatenation, i.e. resulting in an empty string. You also don't really want `ToString` to ever throw.
- `GetHashCode` is necessary to put `Nullable<T>` as a key in a dictionary, or place them into a hashset. It also should not throw, so it has to return something sensible when there's no value.
- The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=netframework-4.7) explains a bit of the underlying concepts.

Accessing the value when there isn't one is forbidden, though. As [Zohar Peled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54532274/methods-on-nullable-types/54532357?noredirect=1#comment95866340_54532357) and [Marc Gravell ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) note in the comments, this is what implicitly happens when calling `GetType`:

> It would seem logical that the compiler could just silently replace `nullableValue.GetType()` with `typeof(SomeT?)`, but that would then mean that it always gives confusing answers when compared to
>
> ```
> object obj = nullableValue;
> Type type = obj.GetType()
> ```
>
> You would expect this to work similarly, but `obj.GetType()` will always return either `typeof(T)` (not `typeof(T?)`), or throw a `NullReferenceException` because `T?` boxes to either a `T` or to `null` (and you can't ask a `null` what type it is)

The mapping of constructs the compiler handles specially is more of less the following:

```
num == null         → !num.HasValue
num != null         → num.HasValue
num = null          → num = new Nullable<int>()
num = 5             → num = new Nullable<int>(5)
(int) num           → num.Value
(object) num        → (object) num.Value         // if HasValue
                    → (object) null              // if !HasValue
```

There's additional support for operators, most importantly comparison operators with non-nullable `T`s and the various operators that work on potential `null` values like `??`, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: And to address the question about why `GetType` returns a null reference exception, read [How to: Identify a nullable type (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/how-to-identify-a-nullable-type). Basically, it's an attempt to box `null`.

Comment: Yes, the underlying behavior of boxing/unboxing explains it. Thanks, however I still think it's not intuitive to ask for a type and get a null exception.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but just a note. You write:

> I would naturally expect the `Value` getter returns `null` value

No! The very reason that `Nullable<T>` exists is to protect you from getting `null` values without checking first.

Comment: It also doesn't help that `Value` is a `T` which must be a value type, so it simply *cannot* be `null`.

Comment: also, `.Value` is typed as `T`, so it *by definition* can't ever return `null` (since you can't have `Nullable<Nullable<T>>`); it is worth noting that `.GetValueOrDefault()` returns without ever failing

Comment: Joey: what I'm trying to say is that that is the very thing that *does* help, and is why `Nullable<T>` was created.

Comment: I think it exists for not protecting you, but allowing you to have null values on types that cannot hold null values (fetched from db or an json endpoint), but yes, I've changed little bit the perception of the Value getter. The underlying value holds the original value that cannot be null, so reading the value by the Value getter can't return null. It seems logical.